Is it guaranteed by the C++ standard that `strrchr` has C++ linkage?
The string.h is a well-known C library, and cstring is a well-known C++ library.
In practical, cstring create an alias for strrchr by using sematics. So std::strrchr is actually ::strrchr. I understand this is a totally compiler implementation issue.
So, let us check string.h. I found it will force C++ linkage of ::strrchr.
/* Tell the caller that we provide correct C++ prototypes.  */
#if defined __cplusplus && (__GNUC_PREREQ (4, 4) \
                || __glibc_clang_prereq (3, 5))
# define __CORRECT_ISO_CPP_STRING_H_PROTO
#endif

...

#ifdef __CORRECT_ISO_CPP_STRING_H_PROTO
extern "C++"
{
extern char *strrchr (char *__s, int __c)
     __THROW __asm ("strrchr") __attribute_pure__ __nonnull ((1));
extern const char *strrchr (const char *__s, int __c)
     __THROW __asm ("strrchr") __attribute_pure__ __nonnull ((1));
...

It is kind of strange to me, because a function in a C library has C++ linkage.
I want to know is it guaranteed by the C++ standard that string.h would have C++ linkage when we have defined __cplusplus macro? Or is it just some implementation detail of compilers and libraries?
NOTE I know there are some disputes between C and C++, which I am not quite familiar with. And I don't want to bring about a new one here. I am a C++ programmer, and my friends and I all have the "memory" here that if one includes string.h, and he/she is using a C function. So it is quite strange to me that it actually has C++ linkage. Because in C++, it actually supports an extern "C" or extern "C++", by which we can choose linkage of  our function. And an extern "C" function works well with C++ functions.

Glibc is not only a C library since C++11. So it is quite strange to me that it actually has C++ linkage. Why not?

@3CxEZiVlQ I am using clang and its library, but all the same IMO. I understand that both the libraries are designed for both C and C++. However, string.h is still a part of the C library rather than C++ library. I wonder why it has C++ codes in it. IMO, the C++ part could be in cstring.

This would seem to be a hack in that specific string.h header to make it compatible with #include <cstring> + using namespace std;, based on using gcc-specific __asm to make the two versions of the functions aliases for each other and match the C linkage when using C++ overloading

I'm not convinced the question as asked is even meaningful. The C++ standard specifies that linkage is part of the function signature, so there can be two overloads simultaneously visible (e.g. to the compiler when compiling a source file) which differ only in one being extern "C" and the other extern "C++".  The standard does not specify how the implementation supports various cases (based on which overloads are visible) - but that might (notionally) be why glibc has the various [non-standard] decorations on the function declaration.

@Peter I don't think that's true. [dcl.link] reads If two declarations declare functions with the same name and parameter-type-list […] to be members of
the same namespace […] and the declarations give the names different language linkages, the program is ill-formed. GCC certainly doesn't think this is allowed and I also don't see how linkage should factor in overload resolution to make this case non-ambiguous


I want to know is it guaranteed by the C++ standard that string.h would have C++ linkage when we have defined __cplusplus macro? Or is it just some implementation detail of compilers and libraries?

To directly quote the standard, section [headers]:

Except as noted in Clause 16 through Clause 32 and Annex D, the contents of each header cname is the same as that of the corresponding header name.h as specified in the C standard library (Clause 2). In the C++ standard library, however, the declarations (except for names which are defined as macros in C) are within namespace scope (6.4.6) of the namespace std. It is unspecified whether these names (including any overloads added in Clause 17 through Clause 32 and Annex D) are first declared within the global namespace scope and are then injected into namespace std by explicit using-declarations (9.9).

(emphasis mine). So the answer is no, this detail is up to the implementation.
That this injection affects the string.h header and not just cstring is a logical conclusion in my opinion. You cannot inject the overloads into global namespace scope if you leave string.h as a regular old C header. This would lead to conflicting declarations if you ever include (most likely indirectly) both headers.
Note that the standard C headers need to be aware of C++ anyway since even without any overloads or other additions, they need to declare extern "C" linkage.

Yes, this is guaranteed because of cstring.syn#note-1

[Note 1: The functions strchr, strpbrk, strrchr, strstr, and memchr, have different signatures in this document, but they have the same behavior as in the C standard library. — end note]

char *strrchr(const char *s, int c);  // C
char *strrchr(char *s, int c);        // C++

The only way to have different signatures is the C++ linkage.

Question is about content of <string.h>, not <cstring>.

This would only seem to be the case if one includes <cstring>.  But the question is asking specifically about #include <string.h>

Does the C++ standard also specify the behavior of string.h? Or it is actually a undefined or discouraged behavior to include string.h in a C++ program?

@calvin C++ always required C++ standard library implementations to provide C headers name.h together with cname, but it was deprecated. The deprecation was removed somewhat recently, so C headers are here to stay. C++ standard mostly relies on C standard to define the contents, it only says what C++ should have available and what are the changes compared to C: https://eel.is/c++draft/support.c.headers

It doesn't. This is details since glibc and libc are not only C runtimes. C++ stuff is guarded with __cplusplus macro. Don't  forget that compilers and runtimes are the same projects.

This guarantees it can't have C language linkage (it could theoretically have an implementation-defined language linkage) but https://eel.is/c++draft/using.linkage#2 guarantees it must have C++ language linkage
